# Custom styling TB-Megamenu

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I'm attempting to custom style the TB-Megamenu because there are a lot of color changes I would like to make. I would also like to change how when the mouse leaves an item it stays that color for a moment before changing back to it's default state. I understand that I can always change the css in a custom stylesheet that's also included like

```
#main-menu-wrapper .tb-megamenu .mega-nav > .active a, #main-menu-wrapper .tb-megamenu .dropdown-menu .mega-nav > .active a {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

But hunting down everything I need to change is quite the task. Especially when trying to hunt down what selections I need to make for things elements are active, or elements that the mouse just left. The fact that the TB-Megamenu is changing the classes also makes it difficult. At the same time the TB-Megamenu is being used elsewhere, and I'd like to keep the default style for them, without affecting other sites that are on the same instance of drupal. 
Is there a better way to accomplish this? Or do I need to continue trying to search and override each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) module has a CSS folder. Use that as your reference. It also has a styles sub-folder that IMO would be of greatest benefit. Just copy one of the whole styles/*.css files over and adapt it. No need to **hunt** it down.

To target a menu on a specific page you will need to inject a CSS class into that page via a preprocess_page hook or [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) or some other preferred method. You need to set it closer to root level (ie html or body tag) than that of `.tb-megamenu` class occurence in the html. Having done that all you need do is prepend your injected class to every single selector that you use, as in:

```
.tb-megamenu.style-black .nav > li > a:focus,
.tb-megamenu.style-black .nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #7bb9e0;
}
```

becomes:

```
.my-page-class .tb-megamenu.style-black .nav > li > a:focus,
.my-page-class .tb-megamenu.style-black .nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #7bb9e0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good route to go. Also I see that there are 3 different style selections in the Megamenu config (Black, Blue, and Green) that correspond to 3 css files in the module folder. Is there a way to add a style to that list? I tried just putting my own stylesheet in there. But it wasn't added to the list.

Comment: You will have to hack it a bit: Look at line 478 of tb_megamenu.functions.inc Then for the style sheet you will rename it and do a replace inside for the color word